# WebView with custom HTTP client

Tags: java, android, webview, apache-httpclient-4.x

My task is to load web site in WebView over HTTPS with unsupported by vanilla Android TLS cipher.
Right now as proof of concept I have implemented apache http client capable of doing http requests to such resources.

What is the best approach to make WebView use my custom client implementation to do all network requests?

Comment: I am starting to think this is impossible. I found `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest()` with which I can make network requests to page resources with my own http client, but this method passes only requested url without related request information (http method GET/POST/..., http headers etc) so it can not be used for real "proxying".

Comment: Just a note, that the request method and headers are available since Android 5.0 in the new version of `shouldInterceptRequest` by means of [WebResourceRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebResourceRequest.html) parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Android 5.0 (API 21+) you can use [`WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest(WebView, WebResourceRequest)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest%29) to intercept web requests with full information and perform them with custom HTTP client.

Thanks @Stan for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the accepted answer is wrong. You do not get full information; what's missing are request bodies.

So you can implement GET or HEAD requests just fine, but POST requests are trickier.

I haven't seen a good solution for that yet. One I've come across uses JavaScript inserted into the page to collect the POST data, hand it to Java via a binding https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript and then performs the request in Java.

Unfortunately, the WebView will try to perform the same request *again*, so you need to add more hackery to make it work.